# Displaying table items with JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage, web-sql

Why can't I display the table item?

My code:

```
function get(){
    db.transaction(function(tx){

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ENTRIES', []);
        function show(){
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            for(i=0; i < len; i++){
                alert(results.rows.item(i).text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And there is this one:

```
function show(tx, results){

    var len = results.rows.length;
    for(i=0; i < len; i++){
                var row = results.rows.item(i);
                console.log(rows.entry);
            }

}
```

Neither of them work. I want to display the results somehow. Maybe in a `for` loop inside HTML in a div.

Plus, the browser doesn't keep the data added:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ENTRIES');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTRIES (id integer primary key autoincrement, entry text)');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (entry) VALUES (5)');
    }
```

I add data form an input, but once I refresh, it's gone. How?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript looks wrong. From the doc, db.transaction has 3 arguments.

```
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

You can do something like this:

```
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ENTRIES', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
       var len = results.rows.length;
       console.log("ENTRIES table: " + len + " rows found.");
       for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
           console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " +                results.rows.item(i).data);
       }
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }
```

Comment: Oh yeah buddy! Thanks! It logs it, but it shows the data as undefined. Why?

Comment: Check how you populate the DB. You can refer here on how to do that http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction